# server not visible using IP address

Tags: networking, webserver, windows-firewall

I used to create servers on Unix easily, but windows is giving me fits.
My goal is a very simple http server on my local windows machine so
that I can access some personal information wherever I am.

Part of the security is using a non-standard port for http: protocol.
(Not great security by itself, I understand.)

I have created (in C#) a server running arbitrarily on port 100.

From a web browser on the machine running the server, I go to either:
http://localhost:100/test
or localhost:100/test
and my web page (3 lines of text) displays in the browser.

My LAN IP is 192.168.1.19

From the same web browser on the machine running the server,
if I go to either:
http://192.168.1.19:100/test
or
192.168.1.19:100/test
and I get the following displayed in the browser:

Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

I have tried to insure windows firewall is open for
port 100, but I'm not positive it is done right.
(The control panel setting had me identify the
executable file of the server.  I expected to tell
it to open port 100, but could find nowhere to do that.)

**I would appreciate any suggestions on getting windows
to make this port available.**

Please don't advise me other ways to approach this
problem, such as remote hosting or loading an existing
server package.  I really want to do it this way for
several reasons too complex to explain here.

I am running on a Windows 10 machine, but saw the same
problem on a Windows XP Pro machine I also tried.

Comment: Have you made sure the firewall rule that opens port 100 is applied to the type of network (Home, Personal or Public) your NIC is on? Its not enough to create a rule to open a port, the rule has to be applied to the type of network that corresponds to your NIC.

Comment: Also, just to make sure that it's an issue with Windows firewall, have you turned it off completely and see if the page loads? And assuming you mean the Bad Request error is happening when you are browsing from another machine, not the one hosting the server? If so, please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: So you created code to build a server.  You want us to troubleshoot your code, the OS, the configuration, and your network?

Have you proven your code works?  How did you do that?  What happens when you try http://172.0.0.1:100 from the machine running the server?  Can you ping the server?  Why are you writing your own code when you can just change ports in Apache http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html ? Do you have a folder called test that the server you wrote has access to?  How do you know it works?

Comment: to ojs: I have not found where I can make such a rule.  I will look for that specifically, but if you can point me to the right control panel I'd appreciate it.

Comment: To red: I DID say specifically that I was using a browser on the same machine as was running the server.  I have not tried turning off the firewall completely to determine if it is the problem.  Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: To Everett: I was specific in my need.  I said in my post that it was running successfully on localhost... which is the same as 127.0.0.1.  As for why I am not running Apache, I said in the last paragraph that I have reasons... why can't you accept that?  [My server is going to do one specific task that would have to be implemented with complex scripting in Apache... and I'd have to configure Apache to turn off all its added functionality that I DON'T want, as every added bit is another possibility for a security hole.  And that's just one of my many reasons.]  Please read more carefully.

Comment: The image [here](https://public.bn1303.df.livefilestore.com/y3pmQKOKYM_2Ci-m2CbWCfSdKvX354eRB1lpwVMgc2GLHG4Irleuj9jVfhl9kh52hmLT1Ls9kWL2ms2jHTL9eSn82SLhqNZV0rf9T-1fepS0Ac/Windows%2520Firewall%2520with%2520Advanced%2520Settings.png?rdrts=118540992) shows a column called Profile. If your rule has All in that profile that means the firewall has applied the rule to all types of connections (Home, Personal or Public). If it set to Domain or Private then it might be the problem.

Comment: @MarkT with arrogance like yours, here, let me spend my time helping you.  Maybe if you read carefully you would have answered some of the other questions.  So let's try this again.  How do you know your code works?  And answer without the attitude.